# Android Studio java autocomplete doesn't work after a while and Android Studio project doesn't recognize some classes

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

The java icon does not appear in the square in the picture and the autocomplete does not work. As an example from the screenshot, the `LiquidPager` color is green and turns white when this problem occurs.

This problem arose after **updating android studio** to **version 4.1.1**. Then I installed the old version again but the problem did not fix.

I did delete `.idea` all `.iml` files inside the project then invalidate & restart build project again. But no luck, no matter what I did it doesn't get resolved. I have an old backup of this project and not a recent one, so I want to get this fixed . No problem with **XML** autocomplete.

[problem screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLhdv.png)

Comment: I recommend deleting all the android studio files and folders that exist in pc like in AppData, users except SDK, and reinstall the android studio with full network connectivity(single network issue and all its boom!!) som make internet connectivity is good. It happens a lot with me

Comment: Make sure "power saving mode" is disable under File menu.